# Laravel - Get HTML of current page or of a view according to a path

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a view `mypage.blade.php` and a route.

The url is like : `https://example.com/mypage/param1/param2`. The route use `param1` and `param2` and generate the page.

**Question 1**

In that page, I try to get its HTML code. Is there a way to do it?. I tried `render()` but I don't get what I want.

**Question 2**

In the view, can I get the HTML code of an other view by specifying a path ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve

Comment: I try to put in a variable the HTML code of the current page.

Comment: Seems like you didn't check basic docs. Check `response`, `view response` and `blade` sections in docs for what you are asking here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You had the right idea.  Not sure why it wouldn't work for you.

In the controller, set the view into a variable:

```
 $view = view('myBaseView', compact('people', 'places', 'things'));
```

Now, if you dump the rendered view variable, you have the page's HTML:

```
dd($view->render());
```

To get the html of another view by specifying the path and using the internal controller, you would need to set up some kind of a wrapper or catch so that the view variable is not returned as a view, but rendered out to html as above.  Your method would need to trap whatever the original controller was sending before it pushed out the view.

Of course, old school php can get the other page's rendered html too possibly if your server is set to allow this:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://mypage.com/');
```

Something else you might find handy is the Laravel sections method.  If you just want to render part of the page you can do so by calling whatever section you want from a partial view:

```
$sections = $view->renderSections(); // returns an associative array of 'content', 'pageHeading' etc

dd($sections['modalContent']); // this will only dump whats in the content section
```

I don't know what you want to do with this html, but if you wish to display it on a page, once you send it (you'd possibly want to return the view along with a compact of the variable $view... as a normal variable if so), remember to use this format:

```
{!! $view !!}
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks! It's useful.
But, I still have a problem and I realise I wan't very clear. I want to get the HTML code when a visitor open the page. I don't want to call this page just to get the HTML code because this page call an API with limited number of access. So, I don't want to waste a call.

Comment: The answer above will work - you can send the variable $view within your view.  This way you don't call twice, but send double the information.  But it sounds like you are looking for something outside a Laravel solution.  *Really* easy would be to just use jquery on the page and send the output wherever you want:  `$("html").html();`

Comment: hi @Watercayman , please can you help me in this, relatively same query, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74931244/how-to-load-compact-view-in-laravel-with-data-in-url ; i am stuck with this and waiting but got no help yet.

Comment: @MohibSalahuddinAyubi, Looks like you got it solved.  Sorry I didn't see it earlier :)