# How to load compact view in laravel with data in url

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I was making PDF from my webpage, but there are few styling which i am unable to load, like display: flex.
So for troubleshoot and go with other approach i decided to fetch first html from views.
my PDF were loading html from view with following code.

**my view url is:** https://digital.xtrazcon.com/reports/17

```
$report = Report::where('id', '=', $id)->firstOrFail();
$pdf = PDF::loadView('reports.container', ['view' => 'show', 'report' => $report, 'pdf_view' => 'yes'])->save($report_path);
```

so for calling rendered html, i tried following codes; but on all i am getting error.
**all code after die are actually my tries.**

```
        $html = view('reports.container', compact(['view' => 'show', 'report' => $id])->render();
        die(var_dump($html));
```

> Says: compact(): Undefined variable $show

```
        $html = view('reports.container', compact(['view' => 'show', 'report' => $report])->render();
        die(var_dump($html));
```

> Says: compact(): Undefined variable $show

Following one loads fine, but on view it gives error of missing data in the view which is **17**

```
        $html = view('reports.container', compact('report'))->render();
        die(var_dump($html));
```

> Says: Undefined variable $view (View: /var/www/vhosts/digital.xtrazcon.com/httpdocs/resources/views/reports/container.blade.php)

> > Line of code, which gives the above error is below

```
    <?php echo $__env->make('reports.' . $view, \Illuminate\Support\Arr::except(get_defined_vars(), ['__data', '__path']))->render(); ?>
```

Please help, how can i call rendered html, so i can fix it for PDF.

**Update Made**

I tried something similar advise here, [Laravel Meaning of Load View function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57969045/laravel-meaning-of-load-view-function)

I have my view path at

> /httpdocs/resources/views/reports/show.blade.php

so i decided to use

> > **reports/show** as a view

I tried following updated code then

```
    $report = Report::where('id', '=', $id);
    $html = view('reports/show', compact('report'));    
    dd($html->render());    
    die();
```

But still getting following error

> > > Property [host] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance. (View: /var/www/vhosts/digital.xtrazcon.com/httpdocs/resources/views/reports/show.blade.php)

Comment: Stop using `compact`. Try `$html = view('reports.container',['view' => 'show', 'report' => $id)->render();` but be aware it's likely your PDF tool can't handle flexbox; most can't.

Comment: sir @ceejayoz then is there any library or any thing that can handle flexbox?

Comment: Every HTML to PDF tool I've used has only supported a limited subset of modern HTML/CSS. It's a little like writing HTML emails.

Comment: unfortunately :-( so it means have to write separate html or css to handle that, similarly it does not allow unfortunately svg images, is there any library that can call svg with pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got that, the previous explanation mentioned at following query is similar and helpful to understand the direction.
[Laravel Meaning of Load View function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57969045/laravel-meaning-of-load-view-function)

i was just missing **firstOrFail()**

> so i added this line, to call report first.

```
$report = Report::where('id', '=', $id)->firstOrFail();
```

> > then i call view in a following way, by adding my parameter in an array.

```
$html = view('reports/show',['report'=>$report]);   
dd($html->render());
```

> > > If i want to use compact, i tried following and works

```
$html = view('reports/show',compact('report'));
```